# CGPoint of tap on UITableViewCell using touchesBegan

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I am needing the `CGPoint` of a tap on my `UITableViewCell`. To do this I want to use the `touchesBegan:withEvent:` method in my subclassed `UITableViewCell`.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(location));
}
```

**How can I forward that from my `UITableViewCell` subclass to my current `viewController` so that I can make an action depending on where in the cell they tapped?**

** I don't want to use a Gesture Recognizer on the cell since it will not allow the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method to be called.

Comment: What's the question? Can you not just add a delegate or action block to the cell that calls back to the viewController

Comment: "I don't want to use a Gesture Recognizer on the cell since it will not allow the didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method to be called" You are _already_ breaking touch response on the table view. Things can't get worse than the code you've already got...

Comment: If you call through to super in your touches began implementation then everything should work as expected

Comment: @Paul.s - I am doing that, but what is the best way to forward that touch point to my viewController?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either delegation or block call back would do it. Below is an example of using blocks

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
  CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

  __weak __typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
  cell.touchedAtPoint = ^(UITableViewCell *cell, CGPoint point) {
    [weakSelf doSomethingWithPoint:point);
  };

  return cell;
}
```

In the cell

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
{
  [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

  UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
  CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];

  void (^touchedAtPoint)(UITableViewCell *, CGPoint) = self.touchedAtPoint;
  if (touchedAtPoint) {
    touchedAtPoint(self, location);
  }
}

- (void)prepareForReuse;
{
  [super prepareForReuse];

  self.touchedAtPoint = nil;
}
```

Declaration of ivar

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^touchedAtPoint)(UITableViewCell *cell, CGPoint point);
```

Comment: What kind of object is `touchedAtPoint`? I need to make it as a property.

Comment: I've add to the answer

Comment: Getting a `Block pointer to non-function type is invalid` error for the `void (^touchedAtPoint) = self.touchedAtPoint;` line.

Comment: Sorry missed off some of the declaration check the line above again

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you!